# How to create a table with query?

Tags: jquery

I am looking to create a table with a jquery.

I have the classic call with jquery but now I am interested to create te table through jquery.

Could anyone help to me?

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8081/getAllUrl",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(listURL) {
                $.each(listURL, function (i) {
                    console.log(listURL[i]);
                });
            }
        });
```

Example of return of listURL

```
[
"https://www.mismarcadores.com/mobile/#android",
"https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/mismarcadores/id766477515",
"https://www.mismarcadores.com/#"
]
```

A simply array list of String !

Regards !

Comment: Include an example of what `http://localhost:8081/getAllUrl` returns.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you looking to use jQuery to dynamically build the HTML for a table and inject it into your page? If so you should [1] determine if you're going to have the table scaffolding (e.g. `table`, `thead`, `th` elements) already on your page to dynamically add rows to and [2] define what your AJAX response looks like in terms of building table rows from the results.

Comment: Hello I updated the code with tthe example that return this simply arraylist, yes I am looking to load dinamically the table @Stevangelista because I would like to create all page with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple table, that you can build upon:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8081/getAllUrl",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (listURL) {
        var table = $("<table>", { class: "simple-table" });
        $.each(listURL, function (i) {
            table.append("<tr><td>" + listURL[i] + "</td></tr>");
        });
        // or some other element
        $("body").append(table);
    }
});
```